# How to put controls within different content placeholder without using form

Tags: asp.net

Situation: I have a master page which has 3 content place holder but no form runat server.
In my Login.aspx I try to fill those place holders but it does't allow me without form runat server tag and once I add more than one form again it shows me :"A page can have only one server-side Form tag."

here is my code :

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="DWDS_Lotus_Care_Final.Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <form id="formUser" runat="server">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" runat="server" Text="Logout" />
            </p>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 93px">
                UserName :
            </td>
            <td style="width: 139px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 307px">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 93px">
                Password :</td>
            <td style="width: 139px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 307px">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 93px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 139px">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" Text="Clear" runat="server" 
            onclick="btnClear_Click" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 307px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkRegister" Text="Register" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </p>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

**here is the master source**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs"     Inherits="DWDS_Lotus_Care_Final.Site1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <title>Consistent</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">

            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="page">



        <%--Here is the sidebar--%>
            <div id="sidebar" style="background-color:#CCCCCC">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    <h3>Links to Other Hospitals</h3>
                    <div class="date-list">
                        <ul class="list date-list">
                            <li class="first"><span class="date">Sunway</span> <a href="#">Sunway Piramid</a></li>
                            <li><span class="date">KPJ</span> <a href="#">Kajang Care Centre</a></li>
                            <li><span class="date">HCC</span> <a href="#">Health Care Center</a></li>
                            <li><span class="date">AlphaH</span> <a href="#">Alpha Health Center</a></li>
                            <li><span class="date">UPC</span> <a href="#">Bangsar Hospital</a></li>
                            <li class="last"><span class="date">TPM</span> <a href="#">Technology Park Hospital</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <br class="clearfix" />
            </div>



            <%--Here is the Content--%>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Welcome to Lotus Care</h2>

                <div class="box">
                     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">

                     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <br class="clearfix" />
            </div>





            <br class="clearfix" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: paste the master page source file ( aspx)

Comment: you cannot use more than one form tag and content place holder should be within form tag

Comment: Place the form tag in the master page and remove them from the place holders

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but once I want to put controls in content place holder it tells me to put it in form with runat server tag. so I only can have one form in one content place holder, but what about the others?!

Comment: so use div or panels instead of forms

Comment: why don't you keep form tag in master page itself?

Comment: I used both div and panel came up with this error :
Control 'ContentPlaceHolder2_btnLogout' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: @Ben-first remove the content place holders and place any content placeholder inside a form tag.

Comment: @Ashwini Verma , Thanks a lot, I used only one form and put all 3 content place holders inside and it works. It was't possible in Pages derived from master page but within master page it is possible.

Can you please reply it as Answer so I can close the topic as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MasterPage:

```
<form runat="server">
   <%-- use form tag only in Master page.--%>
 <div id="content">
 <h2>Welcome to Lotus Care</h2>
 <div class="box">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">

  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
  <br class="clearfix" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Content Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <%-- don't use Form tag here..--%>
  <table style="width: 100%">
  </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

I will use div or panels for this situation

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
<div>
//Place some controls here    
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div>
//Put some controls here 
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
<div>
//Put some more controls here
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot coder. Ashwini Verma's solution worked. I put only one form inside Master page and put all the content place holder inside. In my Login.aspx I just used them without any form or div or panel.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017 u can use contentplaceholder without form tag. Use asp.net 4.6.2